# AWS Cloudwatch Cronjob Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: cron, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I wanted to invoke my **lambda** in every minute during `13.00` and `17.00` UTC except for Tuesday. I wrote the following **cron** expression in cloudwatch rule, but I am getting error that

> Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

```
cron(0/1 13,14,15,16,17 * ? WED-MON *)

cron(* 13,14,15,16,17 * ? WED-MON *)
```

I cross checked the expression with [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru) also.

I even tried to do the following since I was still ok if it run in Tuesday.

```
cron(* 13,14,15,16,17 * * * *)
```

All of them are giving me error. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

did you get a chance to refer this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html?tag=duckduckgo-d-20#RateExpressions? Based on that your expression would look like:
"0/1 13-17 ? * Wed-Mon *"

Let me know how it goes.

Edit: I accidentally used a "*" in place of a "?". I tried "0/1 13-17 ? * Wed-Mon *" and it worked.

Comment: I checked the doc. Also I tried the cron you mentioned. Still not working. Same error.